# Grails jms and atmosphere plugin null springSecurityService injection in services

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, spring-security, jms, atmosphere

### Hello!

I am using grails jms and atmosphere plugin...

When trying to inject springSecurityService into
 Jms-Atmosphere Service class, the principal/currentUser is null while there is a reference to this object (springSecurityService is not null)

```
//Grails Service class
class UserMessageService {

        static transactional = true
        static exposes = ['jms']
        static destination = "queue.usermessage"

        def jmsService
        def springSecurityService

        public def onMessage(msg) {
           sleep(2000) // slow it down
           log.info "sending jms mssage"
           //User is null!!
           User user = springSecurityService.currentUser

           jmsService.send(topic:'msgevent', msg)

           return null
        }
}
```

So I am wondering...

Is it a plugin problem, or is it a problem with listening the events (As an event Listener) publicated from the jms plugin?
I have the same problem when using Atmosphere Hander as a Service using the Atmosphere plugin! In this case the atmosphere service have to be exposed to jms events also!
Please give me some ideas to deal with this... workarounds maybe... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no cookie set in your particular call. Are you using websocket? Make sure, you've got Atmosphere 1.0.0 and have the session support enabled! You will then still need to fetch the authentication from the originating request:

```
if(resource.writer instanceof WebsocketResponseWriter) {
    AtmosphereResource resource = resource.atmosphereResource
    SecurityContext sessionContext = resource.session
       .getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY)
}
```

You would then need to provide the current session context with the authentication from the session context you've found. Make sure you reset the authentication once the request has been handled.

Does this help?